# Suppose $\Omega$ is a star shaped domain that is not equal to the whole complex plane.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Suppose $\Omega$ is a star shaped domain that is not equal to the whole complex plane.

(a) Show that there is some $w \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $f(z) = $log$(z-w)$ (for some branch of log) is a holomorphic function on $\Omega$

(b) Let $v \in \Omega$ show that there is some $\delta > 0$ so that

$|f(z) - (f(v)+2\pi i)| > \delta$ for all $z \in \Omega$

(c) Show that there exists a holomorphic map $F : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $F(\Omega)$ is bounded, that is there exists some $M$ such that if $\eta \in F(\Omega), |\eta| \leq M$.

I have been struggling with part (c) of the problem, can someone please give an argument to the problem and a few guidelines?

Comment: Do you mean $f(z)$ in the first part of your question?

Comment: It is f(x) in part (a), not f(z).

Comment: then part (a) doesn't make sense. On the left, $x$ is a variable, but on the right, $z$ seems to be the variable...

Comment: I am very sorry about this, it should be f(z)  :)